# Illegal NSTableView data source - what did I wrong?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I have an app, where I added simple images (posters) with movie names. But after run, I can see only empty table and an error in console:

> Illegal NSTableView data source ().  Must implement numberOfRowsInTableView: and tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:

Now, in my .xib file I have Table View with `dataSource` and `delegate` linked to the `File's Owner`. Here's the code:

MasterViewController.m

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"
#import "NSObject+IntengineMovieData.h"
#import "NSObject+IntengineMovieDoc.h"

@interface MasterViewController ()

@end

@implementation MasterViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do view setup here.
}

- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
    NSTableCellView *cellView = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:tableColumn.identifier owner:self];

    if([tableColumn.identifier isEqualToString:@"MoviesColumn"]) {
        IntengineMovieDoc *movieDoc = [self.movies objectAtIndex:row];
        cellView.imageView.image = movieDoc.thumbImage;
        cellView.textField.stringValue = movieDoc.data.title;
        return cellView;
    }
    return cellView;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView {
    return [self.movies count];
}

@end
```

What that problem means and how can I fix it in my case?

---

EDIT 1: I have MasterViewController.xib as my Main Interface. I loaded it by this:

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "NSObject+IntengineMovieDoc.h"
#include "MasterViewController.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet MasterViewController *masterViewController;
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    self.masterViewController = [[MasterViewController alloc]
                                 initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController" bundle:nil];

    IntengineMovieDoc *movie1 = [[IntengineMovieDoc alloc] initWithTitle:@"The Godfather" rating:5 thumbImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"TheGodfatherThumb.jpg"] fullImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"TheGodfather.jpg"]];

    IntengineMovieDoc *movie2 = [[IntengineMovieDoc alloc] initWithTitle:@"Tree of Life" rating:4 thumbImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"TreeOfLifeThumb.jpg"] fullImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"TreeOfLife.jpg"]];

    IntengineMovieDoc *movie3 = [[IntengineMovieDoc alloc] initWithTitle:@"Taxi Driver" rating:5 thumbImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"TaxiDriverThumb.jpg"] fullImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"TaxiDriver.jpg"]];

    NSMutableArray *movies = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: movie1, movie2, movie3, nil];
    self.masterViewController.movies = movies;

    [self.window.contentView addSubview:self.masterViewController.view];
    self.masterViewController.view.frame = ((NSView*)self.window.contentView).bounds;
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
}
@end
```

Comment: Add heightForHeaderInSection method

Comment: Nothing happened. Are you sure it is the correct method name for macOS?

Comment: sorry this is iOS method.

Comment: How do you load the nib?

Comment: @ChiragKothiya - indeed, and Xcode didn't underline it as bad apparently.

Comment: @Willeke - check my edit.

Comment: Any other table views in the XIBs? Does reconnecting the delegate help?

Comment: @Willeke I tried reconnecting the delegate, but nothing works... And I have only one table view. Strange, but it seems that I used wrong method name, or I have something wrong with connection...

Comment: I don't know if it is related to the issue but it looks like you've mixed up `tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:` (returns data) and `tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:` (returns a view). If you set the values of the fields in `tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:`, you don't have to implement `tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:`.